# Erro no Android Studio o que fazer?

Tags: android, android-studio

Parece este erro para mim

```
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Rodolfo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

com resolver esse erros

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity);
```

O `R` fica vermelho no código e `Androidmanifest` onde e se inicia com android: tá  em vermelho

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @DiegoFelipe na verdeda o erro na esta aparecendo mais mas no Androidmanifest `android:configChanges, android:theme, android:icon, android:allowBackup,android:versionCode, android:versionName e http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` estão vermelho

Comment: Pelo que vi [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092511/resource-error-in-android-studio-after-update-no-resource-found) pode ser problema de recursos só disponiveis em versões superiores da api, e você está tentando usá-los em apis antigas. Faça o teste alterando a api conforme é dito no link. Não esqueça de dar um clean no projeto depois.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe o engraçado que compilou .

Comment: Quando esse R some, provavelmente algum XML seu está inválido.

Comment: Alteraste alguma configuração do manifest recentemente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rodolfo eu tive um erro bem similar ao seu. O meu problema era que, no arquivo `build.gradle`, aquele que você configura o `SDK` pra qual versão vai compilar essas coisas, as propriedades de compilação estavam em desacordo com as dependências.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

compile 'com.android.support:*-v7:23.1.1'
```

Como está seu arquivo atualmente. Envie ele pra nós darmos uma olhada.